# Which video format to choose for MPMoviePlayerController?

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

Is that mp4? Which exact encoding results in best performance? Couldn't find it in the class reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Apple Docs:

> This class plays any movie or audio
>   file supported in iOS. This includes
>   both streamed content and fixed-length
>   files. For movie files, this typically
>   means files with the extensions .mov,
>   .mp4, .mpv, and .3gp and using one of
>   the following compression standards:
>
> H.264 Baseline Profile Level 3.0
>   video, up to 640 x 480 at 30 fps. (The
>   Baseline profile does not support B
>   frames.) MPEG-4 Part 2 video (Simple
>   Profile) If you use this class to play
>   audio files, it displays a white
>   screen with a QuickTime logo while the
>   audio plays. For audio files, this
>   class supports AAC-LC audio at up to
>   48 kHz, and MP3 (MPEG-1 Audio Layer 3)
>   up to 48 kHz, stereo audio.